# Is OpenStack live migration possible without shared storage?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, openstack

Like many people I am considering creating 'private cloud' using either OpenStack or VMware.

VMware vMotion has a nice feature which allows Live Migration of VMs even without shared storage. I have tried this feature in a lab environment and it works well. This feature is not without it's downsides but it is appealing for sites which need a simple VM environment and don't want to spring for the complexity and expense of shared storage. Shared storage can easily add $50-100K to the cost of a Virtual/Cloud infrastructure. More information on this feature at:

- [ESXi and vCenter Server 5.1 Documentation > vCenter Server and Host Management > Migrating Virtual Machines in the vSphere Web Client](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.vcenterhost.doc/GUID-561681D9-6511-44DF-B169-F20E6CA94944.html)
- [Techtarget: shared nothing live migration](http://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/definition/shared-nothing-live-migration).

Does OpenStack using KVM offer a similar feature? Can OpenStack do live migration without shared storage? KVM is the default hypervisor for OpenStack and we'd prefer to stick with the default unless there is a compelling reason to use something else.

Answer (score 6):

Openstack supports [live migration without shared storage (with reservation)](http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/openstack-ops/content/live_migration.html):

> Theoretically live migration can be done with non-shared storage,
>   using a feature known as KVM live block migration. However, this is a
>   little-known feature in OpenStack, with limited testing when compared
>   to live migration, and is slated for deprecation in KVM upstream.

This doc is incomplete, however. One implementation of live migration was deprecated but a new (and better) implementation was done.

There was [some discussion](https://lists.launchpad.net/openstack/msg22953.html) about this on the Openstack mailing list Apr 2013 where Daniel Berrange says:

> What I wrote above about the existing impl is still accurate. The new
>   block migration code is now merged into libvirt and makes use of an
>   NBD server built-in to the QMEU process todo block migration. API wise
>   it should actually work in the same way as the existing deprecated
>   block migration code.  So if you have new enough libvirt and new
>   enough KVM, it probably ought to 'just work' with openstack without
>   needing any code changes in nova. I have not actually tested this
>   myself though.

Comment: live_migration.html certainly looks out-of-date based on the conversation from Daniel Berrange. I wonder if a newer version of that page is in the works.

Comment: Can someone tell me what versions of libvirt and KVM are "new enough"? [Daniel Berrange says](https://lists.launchpad.net/openstack/msg22953.html) _"So if you have new enough libvirt and new enough KVM, it probably ought to 'just work' with openstack without needing any code changes in nova."_

Comment: It would be great to have something close to an authoritative answer. Another user on the list provided some information, but asked for clarification. [Sylvain Bauza](https://lists.launchpad.net/openstack/msg22979.html) says "_Waiting Daniel's reply, but afaik, the new NBD server is available since qemu-1.4 and libvirt 1.0.2_"